# the results of mlmodel using ANE is wrong, but results of gpu and cpu are correct

Tags: deep-learning, coreml, onnx, onnx-coreml

There is a strange problem about my fcn-mobilenetv2 mlmodel. I convert this mlmodel from onnx using onnx-coreml tool with target=ios12. It can run on ANE because the speed is much faster than CpuAndGpu. However the results of ANE are totally wrong, but the results of cpu-only and CpuAndGpu are correct, no matter the iphone'os is ios12 or ios13.

Then I tried to convert the onnx to mlmodel by setting the target=ios13. It runs successfully on cpu, CpuAndGpu and ANE, and the results are all correct on ios13.

So I am confused that where the bug comes from. The bug may be from the onnx-coreml convert tool or from the coreml sdk in the ios?

xcode 11.3
macos 10.15
iphonexs ios13 and ios 12

Comment: Do you get any error messages in the console when you run on the ANE?

Comment: No any error messages occurred in the console on the ANE. So it was very strange.

Comment: Here are the onnx and mlmodel. I have put them on google drive.  
https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/165ykvpEvM8SWe3CniuCv2ZWb1vv2_rO7?usp=sharing

Comment: The only situation I have seen this, is when you have numeric underflow, i.e. the activations in your model become too small and get rounded down to zeros. If this is the case, then try running the model on the GPU but with `allowLowPrecisionAccumulationOnGPU` set to true. Does it still work on the GPU now or does it also fail?

Comment: Thanks. I have tried to set allowLowPrecisionAccumulationOnGPU = true for GPU. It still works and gets the correct result.

Comment: Then your only option is to remove layers from the model until it works on the ANE. Now you know which layer stops it from working. Replace that layer with something else.